# Trigger remote shutdown script by modifying index.html Secure?

Tags: security, web

I had an idea, how secure is it?

I have a computer running and I want to turn it off remotely, without using too much mobile data.

So I have a webpage.

My computer is running a python script that's using wget to download this webpage's index.html every 30 minutes. The script checks if the index has a username a password and a random phrase in it.

If the index has the right credentials, the python script reads it, hashes it and shuts my PC down.

Comment: See my comment to @ELLIOTTCABLE 's answer. Use ssh or a signed mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting your password *anywhere* in plaintext is extremely dangerous.

You're relying on what's called ‘security through obscurity’: “Theoretically, nobody knows where this HTML page is; so it must be secure to put private data on it.” Unfortunately, this isn't necessarily true: computation time and network-access is cheap. *Really* cheap, in bulk. It's very accessible for nefarious agents to scan for arbitrary URLs on arbitrary endpoints (especially now that you've declared here that you're planning on doing so ;).

Although I'd posit that your solution is inherently flawed; you *can* make it slightly more secure by encoding the credentials using a shared-secret known ahead-of-time to both your computer and your mobile device (assuming you're writing the code for this solution on your phone, yourself.) This way, at least, they're not *on the wire* in plaintext. :P

Disclaimer: I'm not an infosec professional (which makes it even more worrying that this was obviously flawed, even to me!)

Comment: Even if it was expensive to find the password and the "damage" does not exceed a PC shut down, the concept is flawed. En*crypting* the password with a synchronous cipher surely helps, since the decrypted password would not match the stored password if the cipher text was modified. However, the password had to be changed for each instance, otherwise various attacks could be used to force a shutdown. The other option would be to sign the encrypted password. However, this all seems odd to me. A signed e-Mail with the word "shutdown" could be verified to be from OP and used to trigger a shutdown.